# Bookmarklet Image Question

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I'm trying to make bookmarklet to

**IF(url ends in .jpg || .png || .jpeg)**
dosomething(the url)

**ELSE**
onhover of any image, put a 50% opacity red cover over it. And `onclick something(this.src)`

Catch, there might be a link already around it:

Comment: This is not a question, but a request for people to do the job for you. It would be better if you could break this task into several problems (fundamentals of a bookmarklet, testing current URL, adding an overlay to an existing image, etc.) that you can ask as individual, digestible questions, both for your own sake and for the content at SO.

Answer (score 0):

Use "javscript:" to create a bookmarklet. For example, here is the bookmarklet code to bookmark a page using Google Bookmarks:

```
javascript:(function(){var%20a=window,b=document,c=encodeURIComponent,d=a.open("http://www.google.com/bookmarks/mark?op=edit&output=popup&bkmk="+c(b.location)+"&title="+c(b.title),"bkmk_popup","left="+((a.screenX||a.screenLeft)+10)+",top="+((a.screenY||a.screenTop)+10)+",height=420px,width=550px,resizable=1,alwaysRaised=1");a.setTimeout(function(){d.focus()},300)})();
```

I think "window.location.href" will give you the URL of the page. Don't know about the opacity offhand